# Backbone: Many small requests for model changes vs one collection sync?

Tags: backbone.js

What is a general good practice for when some action - changes multiple models in Backbone.js:

1. Trigger multiple PUT requests for each `mode.save()`
2. Single request to sync the entire collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case if the quantity of the changed models greater than 1 - definitely it should be the second item.

Answer (score 1):

I like the first option, but I'd recommend you implement a PATCH behavior (only send updated attributes) to keep the requests as small as possible. This method gives you a more native "auto-save" feel like Google Docs. Of course, this all depends on your app and what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, good REST api practice seems to suggest that you should `update, save, create, delete` single instances of persistent elements. In fact, you will find that a `Backbone.Collection` object does not implement these methods.

Also, if you use a standard URI scheme for your data access point, you will notice that a collection does not have a unique id.

```
GET  /models       //to get all items,
GET  /models/:id   //to read an element,
PUT  /models/:id   //to update an element,
POST /models/:id   //to create an element,
DELETE /models/:id //to delete an element.
```

If you need to update every model of a collection on the server at once, maybe you need to ask why and there might be some re-thinking of the model structure. Maybe there should be a separate model holding that common information.

As suggested by Bart, you could implement a `PATCH` method to update only changed attributes of a particular element, thus saving bandwidth.